# Finding number of elements of a set that are divisible by a number.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Say for instance that I have a set of positive even integers A = {2, 4, 6, 8, ... 2000}.

How would I find the number of elements in this set that are divisible by some integer?

For instance, I understand that if, say, between 0 and 2000 there are (2000-2)/3 = 666 numbers divisible by 3, then somehow the inclusion-exclusion principle might apply to exclude odd numbers from this count, I am just not sure how.

Comment: Divide all numbers in the set by $2$, so you now have $\{1,2,3,\ldots,1000\}$. If a number in the original set was divisible by some odd number $k$, the corresponding element will still be divisible by $k$ in the new set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we want to find how many of the even integers from $2$ to $2000$ are divisible by $m$. It is convenient to divide into two cases: (i) $m$ even and (ii) $m$ odd.

(i) If $m$ is even, say $m=2n$, we want to find the number of integers from $1$ to $1000$ that are divisible by $n$. You know how to do that.

(ii) Now let $m$ be odd. Then $m$ divides $2k$ if and only if $m$ divides $k$. So we want to find the number of integers between $1$ and $1000$ that are divisible by $m$. Again, you know how to do that.